# Advice for GRE exam (Surface area of cylinder)

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

I need from experienced people  such advice, for example, it is given on the exam that we have  cylinder with base radius $3$ and height $4$. The question is to calculate the surface area. Generally, as I know the formula  for  surface area  of cylinder used in GRE exam is $2\pi r^2+2\pi rh$, but we have two definitions of  surface area. One is lateral,  which is  just only the second part or $2\pi rh$ and total  surface area  which is the complete  formula  given above.

Please help me determine which one is required to find surface area on the GRE exam?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not taken GRE, but I guess "surface area" should mean areas from every part of the surface, including top and bottom.

Comment: i think we really need to see the original question for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context. If your cylinder is a small object and you are asked to gift wrap it, for example, then you have to consider the total surface area, because you want to cover the whole object, lateral + bases.

If you are asked to create a container, whose base is on earth, and whose top will be open from which you would be pouring things into the cylinder then you are to calculate the lateral surface area only as you are not interested in covering the base and the top.

Comment: but it should be clarified yes in problem

Comment: You will be given context in the question. You have to determine on your own whether it's total surface area or the lateral.

Comment: but it is not right

Comment: @giorgi: It would be better if you let us to take a look at the original question as akkk commented.